# Creating a constant from function with multiple return values

Tags: ios, swift

I have looked at the Apple guide to swift and functions with multiple return values but still unsure on this. Possibly it is just a sytanx issue.

I have a function which returns two values for example (CGPoint, CGVector) like this.

```
func returnTwoValues() -> (pointReturned: CGPoint, vectorReturned: CGVector) {
 return ...
}
```

I am looking to create a let that is the result from just one of these values. I.e.

```
let newPoint = returnTwoValues.pointReturned
```

But this does not work, so how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func returnTwoValues() -> (pointReturned: CGPoint, vectorReturned: CGVector) {
    return ...
}
```

You would use

```
var twoValues = returnTwoValues()
var pointReturned = twoValues.pointReturned
```

To get the value, although

```
var pointReturned = returnTwoValues().pointReturned also work.
```

Maybe an easier example is

```
func getTwoInts() -> (intOne:Int, intTwo:Int){
    return (1,2)
}

var one = getTwoInts().intOne
var twoInts = getTwoInts()
var alsoOne = twoInts.intOne
var (oneInt,_) = getTwoInts()
var yetAnotherOne = getTwoInts().0
```

There you have 4 ways to get your value ;) (thanks to Martin R. for the 3rd)

Comment: Of course you do :) Thanks it seems so obvious looking at it now

Comment: Note that `let (one, _) = getTwoInts()` does also work.

Comment: And even `getTwoInts().0` works (grabs the first value inside the tuple)

Comment: I think `var alsoOne = twoInts.intOne` is like my question example which was not working for me.

Comment: no, your question example is like  `var one = getTwoInts().intOne` but you just forget the '()'

Comment: Ah yes, I see what you are doing there. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This does in fact work, you just aren't calling the function. It's trying to find a member named `pointReturned` on the function itself, rather than on the return value. Add parens after the function name:

```
let newPoint = returnTwoValues().pointReturned
```